# Automatic scale items sizes with Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor

Tags: android, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm using dip as unit in my apps. I figured out, that width isn't exact on different devices, for example: 292 dip width will cause different results on 160 and 320 dpi devices.

This is my basic approach:

```
 <ImageView id="panelImage" width="292" image="/images/loginPanel.png"></ImageView>
```

Before showing the element I check the device density factor (with Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor) and upscale the image width with 160/Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor like this:

```
 $.panelImage.width = $.panelImage.width * 160 / Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor;
```

It works, but my problem is that I have to recalculate size values on EVERY item...
Is there any other solution for this?

The best would be something like this (BUT ITS NOT WORKING!!!):

```
 <ImageView id="panelImage" width="(292*160/Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor)" image="/images/loginPanel.png"></ImageView>
```

(So, I try to use the multiplication in Alloy View definition XML file.)

Any idea?

Comment: Can you write your full code !

Comment: Do you set your default unit to `dp`? (`<property name="ti.ui.defaultunit" type="string">dp</property>`) If yes, there shouldn't be much difference on different devices.

Comment: What is exactly that you want the width of the image to be in relation to the width of the screen? A fixed percentage? Then use `"x%`. A more or less fixed width (in cm) when displayed on devices of different dpi? Then use `dp` (the default).